# win32gui.FindWindow - screenshot loop not updating on specific windows

Tags: python, opencv, win32gui

I'm running into an issue while using OpenCV. win32gui.FindWindow finds the window I need by its title, but not all applications are displayed. For example, Steam and Discord - show a black screen and nothing else. For example, a notepad application - captures and displays without problems. I use the OpenCV library for display.

this code is from
https://github.com/learncodebygaming/opencv_tutorials/tree/master/004_window_capture

it seems like it captures the first screenshot and the loop is running due to the output in the terminal. I don't know why the screenshot wouldn't update.

**windowcapture.py**

```
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con


class WindowCapture:

    w = 0
    h = 0
    hwnd = None
    cropped_x = 0
    cropped_y = 0
    offset_x = 0
    offset_y = 0

    def __init__(self, window_name):
        self.hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
        if not self.hwnd:
            raise Exception('Window not found: {}'.format(window_name))

        window_rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(self.hwnd)
        self.w = window_rect[2] - window_rect[0]
        self.h = window_rect[3] - window_rect[1]

        border_pixels = 8
        titlebar_pixels = 30
        self.w = self.w - (border_pixels * 2)
        self.h = self.h - titlebar_pixels - border_pixels
        self.cropped_x = border_pixels
        self.cropped_y = titlebar_pixels

        self.offset_x = window_rect[0] + self.cropped_x
        self.offset_y = window_rect[1] + self.cropped_y

    def get_screenshot(self):

        wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.hwnd)
        dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
        cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
        dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, self.w, self.h)
        cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
        cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (self.w, self.h), dcObj, (self.cropped_x, self.cropped_y), win32con.SRCCOPY)

        signedIntsArray = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
        img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
        img.shape = (self.h, self.w, 4)

        dcObj.DeleteDC()
        cDC.DeleteDC()
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.hwnd, wDC)
        win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())

        img = img[...,:3]

        img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)

        return img

    def list_window_names(self):
        def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
            if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
                print(hex(hwnd), win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
        win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)

    def get_screen_position(self, pos):
        return (pos[0] + self.offset_x, pos[1] + self.offset_y) ``
```

Comment: Maybe you can implement pyautogui and pygetwindow to fix it.

Comment: this method is outdated. it won't work with arbitrary types of windows (3d graphics windows can fail). AND you failed to mention where you got this code from.

Comment: Use the window DC, you can only copy the display content of window use GDI, GDI+ to paint themselfs. While if the application is using D2D, D3D, OpenGL, you will failed to get the window's display content and got a totally black bitmap from the DC.